# gss_display_name() failed: A required input parameter could not be read: An invalid name was supplied (, Unknown error)

Tags: apache, kerberos, gssapi, mod-auth-kerb

I'm trying to setup Kerberos authentication on Apache 2.2.15-30 (CentOs 6.5), and am facing an issue that I'm not able to debug or solve. I can see the TGS request in the KDC log and Firefox sends the correct Authorization: Negotiate header, but something in Apache goes wrong and I'm getting an HTTP 500.

### krb5kdc.log

```
Jul 02 20:59:03 infa.domain.local krb5kdc[1847](info): TGS_REQ (6 etypes {18 17 16 23 25 26}) 192.168.218.201: ISSUE: authtime 1404320175, etypes {rep=23 tkt=23 ses=23}, Administrator@DOMAIN.LOCAL for HTTP/infa.domain.local@DOMAIN.LOCAL
```

### Apache error_log

```
[Wed Jul 02 20:59:01 2014] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1940): [client 192.168.218.1] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Wed Jul 02 20:59:03 2014] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1940): [client 192.168.218.1] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Wed Jul 02 20:59:03 2014] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1279): [client 192.168.218.1] Acquiring creds for HTTP/infa.domain.local
[Wed Jul 02 20:59:03 2014] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1692): [client 192.168.218.1] Verifying client data using KRB5 GSS-API
[Wed Jul 02 20:59:03 2014] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1708): [client 192.168.218.1] Client didn't delegate us their credential
[Wed Jul 02 20:59:03 2014] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1727): [client 192.168.218.1] GSS-API token of length 941 bytes will be sent back
[Wed Jul 02 20:59:03 2014] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1139): [client 192.168.218.1] GSS-API major_status:01020000, minor_status:00000000
[Wed Jul 02 20:59:03 2014] [error] [client 192.168.218.1] gss_display_name() failed: A required input parameter could not be read: An invalid name was supplied (, Unknown error)
```

### HTTP dump

```
GET http://infa.domain.local/server-status HTTP/1.1
Host: infa.domain.local
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Date: Wed, 02 Jul 2014 19:32:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
Content-Length: 484
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

GET http://infa.domain.local/server-status HTTP/1.1
Host: infa.domain.local
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Authorization: Negotiate YIID5QYGKwYBBQUCoIID2TCCA9WgCjAIBgYrBgEFAgWiggPFBIIDwWCCA70GBisGAQUCBQUBMBChDgQMRE9NQUlOLkxPQ0FMbIIDnTCCA5mhAwIBBaIDAgEMo4IDFzCCAxMwggIvoQMCAQGiggImBIICIm6CAh4wggIaoAMCAQ  WhAwIBDqIHAwUAAAAAAKOCAU9hggFLMIIBR6ADAgEFoQ4bDERPTUFJTi5MT0NBTKIhMB+gAwIBAqEYMBYbBmtyYnRndBsMRE9NQUlOLkxPQ0FMo4IBCzCCAQegAwIBEqEDAgEBooH6BIH3jDiOe80e8vCv7Tmsd+t0spncJWnD  v99vLDpi5PYc1Gj8vGH7xJxnz4dsr6WavFLmgYCRnvrF+Y+lU/QVF/AUNiqIG7ifGAJGD4IKHzcyYfNo9BLlNBGBckLdIhC3o2G8VfHWxv+Zo6DNfZUJsIVfoN2bls2C8K9K2pv/qd/FHR96+3JpCkRSb2tKqh2VQBA2mplvJML38nvHQkp5Y0rHQ  ecbc0bHns1ddh/RLIlPcwdy8r7xDx7m5QUWH3gI6nSEhrcd/sIKoRJ88ezcMfqumXq2UxvBdBJAH86q9r9r/t74jXpyDFlRgF/Z6OLMwMdus2AkBNrbiaSBsTCBrqADAgEXooGmBIGj4DUpIRQjvddUEpp7sft5UjlnOPOCia9BSyxYBszOihLHr2D  2B6mL6fmqx7IcAVfVzV66B/gqQ4roAh0z4YKensKtqIAG7au2RsXtYNAjEgUFgh7dEE7kACUFoVB2VUK2mtjuHabbwMZ4gprrRIgDeFqROIhxWasVgxhak6dXQAKGEyvVlGoeLTJTPER5s2tcDRkoVTLFO0hBJxarNI/GTk1e1jCB3aEEAgIAi  KKB1ASB0aCBzjCBy6EcMBqgBAIC/3ahEgQQSjwHqwdg2yuvh3nbGzDVuqKBqjCBp6ADAgEXooGfBIGccNThLwiDzyz8cJYPfI6hU505ydEQdRt6N036ZZ98Y49YfV+WWpCgXxhmL/8zhilAC2mQi5cvE5XOJOzGrWHnzl6AO1KfJQKjvogV  zrFhdoPMVssGnBkrD40fsIA2uPJ2e0OeKRC/tOizUg8tVIdhkoivnh69Q1BDAx3JFjx3txRtDoSZHz6x4mlBSs72xFIlIkA7yhXH+nmml4yfpHIwcKAHAwUAUIEAAKIOGwxET01BSU4uTE9DQUyjJDAioAMCAQOhGzAZGwRIVFRQGxFpbmZh  LmRvbWFpbi5sb2NhbKURGA8yMDE0MDcwMzAyNTYxNlqnBgIEU7ReW6gUMBICARICARECARACARcCARkCARo=

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Wed, 02 Jul 2014 19:32:42 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate    oYIDqTCCA6WgAwoBAaEIBgYrBgEFAgWiggOSBIIDjgUBMBChDgQMRE9NQUlOLkxPQ0FMbYIDdjCCA3KgAwIBBaEDAgENooHVMIHSMIHPoQQCAgCIooHGBIHDoIHAMIG9oIG6MIG3oAMCAReiga8Egawhq77nnFYKOC2elIoQEMv  3HoPncmPLVp6/yr+HtLIuoyAsAUdbvyXars5ixGdPlg1IaceQQ3ThVvvsRthV86O4M2l55LfhlfIINZr7xQks3EKTAEA1OfsggBXdmShHV/29W2iLaQP60BvBlYCOGePMyMKp8jcgdNUQ6jLqq6No0Qk7Kro8IIjESMmVR3BAndbUfpDNYqO+IxY  am/pl96xCQgu4iNznoglrYBf7ow4bDERPTUFJTi5MT0NBTKQaMBigAwIBAaERMA8bDUFkbWluaXN0cmF0b3KlggFjYYIBXzCCAVugAwIBBaEOGwxET01BSU4uTE9DQUyiJDAioAMCAQOhGzAZGwRIVFRQGxFpbmZhLmRvbWFpbi5sb  2NhbKOCARwwggEYoAMCARehAwIBAaKCAQoEggEGyeo+gzn7hHLgwIGfZiT3kfiua+yD1d0EDhyoAmctFzukkw7xqdyMZn+gfDna6O0WI7TC6Yv2pQqg1Ph76SZ11ZQu4xXn4FBPu3G9LwbPUxN9+cohhCTPmAX6SLyNu7n9UAKLsccjb  kLq8HJjUgzfLus6AqUeerqjc3eSyr+r1onfQSL9JCNtpOUWtuxGIThTQfOXEYVlVyjMi37bnAFPMrxPERL/7m3vYm3x60HBu5KHy7xfbab8jftIsr33Z/2nnMxNi5LjqVBail4BpZiuRCMmko566KSLKWRSpvr6x/YUR5TPmhXjO3YGdi2VucDn6QW  t81q2dQSYvAQnbuHDL84IQUY126aB+jCB96ADAgEXooHvBIHsmFwxE55S5Gi5VkPG0cS11MHsQvllqJAIxGMkzakyyYCfMKCpHFfyIf/2bIGPvSyCCWOqFxnMOA1a/c2d3eUk6Yr+H5c8PDFePxVbKijvZRVRVJ1pAifpm9kUoKcGMo0SH  9m0H4yu94/ESE7QbEcx7pQac1Udq894rgF7OmnQXZZ6mX2VUrIb0xHxaaj9oR8+zC8vGWyyqVSZhtURxQ8Anr+MifqWKPP2QpWFohptl/zl8bYmMqs1nEH3TIe1wvtOgeqGh6KumbC4rc9IVCN8rx+3XCVr/2BM27nURT21MUzwU1tbpQM  LSqT0gFE=
Content-Length: 617
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

### kdc.conf

```
[kdcdefaults]
kdc_ports = 88
kdc_tcp_ports = 88

[realms]
DOMAIN.LOCAL = {
  #master_key_type = aes256-cts
  acl_file = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
  dict_file = /usr/share/dict/words
  admin_keytab = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab
  forwardable = true
  proxiable = true
  supported_enctypes = rc4-hmac:normal
}
```

### /etc/krb5.conf

```
[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
default_realm = DOMAIN.LOCAL
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
proxiable = true
default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac
default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac

[realms]
DOMAIN.LOCAL = {
  kdc = infa.domain.local:88
  admin_server = infa.domain.local:749
}

[domain_realm]
.domain.local = DOMAIN.LOCAL
domain.local = DOMAIN.LOCAL
```

### auth_kerb.conf

```
LoadModule auth_kerb_module modules/mod_auth_kerb.so

<Location /server-status>
  #SSLRequireSSL
  AuthType Kerberos
  AuthName "Kerberos Login"
  KrbMethodNegotiate On
  KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
  KrbAuthRealms DOMAIN.LOCAL
  Krb5KeyTab /etc/httpd/conf/http.keytab
  KrbServiceName HTTP/infa.domain.local
  require valid-user
</Location>
```

### klist -e -k /etc/httpd/conf/http.keytabb

```
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/httpd/conf/http.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 HTTP/infa.domain.local@DOMAIN.LOCAL (arcfour-hmac)
```

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem might be? I'd be very thankful for any comments.

Thank you,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

I got this exactmessage when the client's clock skew was too great.  Setting the clock (and enabling ntp :-) got it working.